# for loop result 0 in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am a newbie in C++, I started to learn coding in C++ two weeks ago. Why does my code below always give me result 0 when I build and run? Please help

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int input = 1;
    cout << "input your number : \n";
    cin >> input;

    int faktorial = 1;

    for(int i=1;i<=input;i++)
    {
        faktorial = faktorial * i;
    }
    cout << "factorial value from number  " << input << " is " << faktorial << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is your `input`?

Comment: no it [does not](https://ideone.com/wawK2i)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aa81985a7351520); I got 720 for an input of 6 (check command line). Please provide a [mcve]. In the case of interactive input, this means providing the input values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code works: https://ideone.com/CYFaxo

I suspect your problem is, you are looking at *program exit code*. When you don't return any value from `main`, program exit code is 0 (this is special case, and only non-void function where you may leave the return statement out), which conventionally means success (non-zero exit code usually indicates some kind of error, by convention).

Try to find the program output from your IDE, it should have the correct printout.

Comment: Good guess, let's see if the OP confirms.

Comment: i add return 0; and it works, thanks a lot

Comment: @doughstone - If it's the answer, you should accept it.